# Embedding Symfony controllers from other bundles

Tags: php, symfony, twig

This seems to be an interesting issue, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something because it should be simple, but isn't.

### Scenario

1. I have one bundle named `AcmePageBundle`
2. Another bundle named `AcmeGalleryBundle`
3. I want to [load an embedded view from the controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) using the `AcmeGalleryBundle` bundle into a template file on `AcmePageBundle`

### Code

#### AcmeGalleryBundle\Controller\DisplayController.php

```
class DisplayController extends Controller
{
    public function embedAction($galleryId)
    {
        $gallery = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeGalleryBundle')->find($galleryId);
        if (!$gallery) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Gallery could not be found');
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeGalleryBundle:Display:embed.html.twig', array(
            'gallery' => $gallery,
        ));
    }
}
```

#### AcmeGalleryBundle\Resources\views\Display\embed.html.twig

```
  <div class="gallery">
  {% for photo in gallery.photos %}
    <a href="{{ photo.webPath }}" rel="shadowbox[gallery];">
      <img src="{{ photo.webPath }}" height="100" width="100">
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

#### AcmePageBundle\Resources\views\Default\index.html.twig

```
{# ... extra HTML content #}
  <h2>Gallery</h2>
  {{ render(controller('AcmeGalleryBundle:Display:embed', {
      'galleryId': 123
  })) }}
{# rest of the HTML content #}
```

### Errors

When trying to render the page that uses `AcmePageBundle:Default:index.html.twig`, I get

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Class 'AcmeGalleryBundle' does not exist") in AcmePageBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 18.

but of course, `AcmeGalleryBundle` does in fact exist. I'm suspecting a scope problem that I've missed somewhere.

### Troubleshooting

1. Ensured that `AcmeGalleryBundle` is loaded in the `AppKernel.php` file
2. Tried adding `use Acme\GalleryBundle` to the top of the `AcmePageBundle.php` bundle file.
3. [Found an issue on GitHub relating to the problem with no response from the devs yet.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12271) I've added my own comments - this may in fact be a bug.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in this line:

```
$gallery = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeGalleryBundle')->find($galleryId);
```

The command `getRepository('AcmeGalleryBundle')` needs to include the entity I'm trying to load the repository for in question. Correct code is:

```
$gallery = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeGalleryBundle:Gallery')->find($galleryId);
```

I mistakenly thought this was an issue with the `render(controller(...))` functionality. After that fix, everything works as it should. Next time I should be looking closer at my stack trace!